What is the power of formal language?
Which one will be the k-th power of that language:
$L = \{a^n b^m : n, m \geq 1\}$

$L^k=$$\{(a^nb^m)^k: n, m \geq 1\}$
$L^k=$$\{a^{n_1}b^{m_1}a^{n_2}b^{m_2}...a^{n_k}b^{m_k}: n_1, m_1, n_2, m_2, ..., n_k,m_k \geq 1\}$

Or none of above?

The second definition is correct. We need several definitions, according to Hopcroft and Ullman:

The concatenation of $L_1$ and $L_2$, denoted $L_1L_2$, is the set $\{xy|\text{$x$ is in $L_1$ and $y$ is in $L_2$}\}$.

For example, $L_1=\{a,b\},L_2=\{c,d\}$ then $L_1L_2=\{ac,ad,bc,bd\}$.

Define $L^0=\{\epsilon\}$ and $L^i=LL^{i-1}$ for $i\ge 1$.

Thus, we infer that $L^k$ is the set of concatenation of $k$ strings in $L$.
